# Set variable in workflow run script, but it doesn't work

Tags: docker, shell, github-actions

```yaml
        run: |
          ContainerId=$(sudo docker ps -q -f name=${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}) &&
          ImageId=$(sudo docker inspect -f '{{.Image}}' $containerId) &&
          echo $ContainerId &&
          echo $ImageId &&
          if [ $ContainerId ]; then
              sudo docker stop ${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }} &&
              sudo docker rm ${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }} &&
              sudo docker rmi $imageId
          fi &&
```

`env.IMAGE_NAME` is miro.

```
sudo docker ps -q -f name=${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
```

get containerID by this command.

```
sudo docker inspect -f '{{.Image}}' $containerId
```

get imageID by this command. Then, remove docker image by this ID.

I try same operation in EC2, It works. But in GitHub Actions workflow run scripts, it doesn't work. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Where is `IMAGE_ID` defined?

Comment: @Turing85
get imageID by `sudo docker inspect -f '{{.Image}}' $containerId` this command

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I wanted to ask about `IMAGE_NAME`. not `IMAGE_ID`.

Comment: What do you mean by that it doesn't work? Do you see any errors in the logs? Remove all those trailing && and observe where it fails exactly.

Comment: echo $ContainerId &&
echo $ImageId

It doesn't print anything at log.
Is there any problem if I remove && operator?

Comment: You are assigning `ContainerId` with a capital C, but then trying to use `$containerId`. Voting to close as simple typo.